# Dynamic Arrays and memory

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

This is a very basic random question I had but saw no answers here or online. 
When creating a dynamic array, we set it to a certain location in memory. Is it possible to make an array that eventually is too big for that memory slot? If so, how is this handled? Is this something that is automatically done by c++ or do we have to do it ourselves?

I am learning linked lists and I know we set each Node to a memory location. But
when using an array, we don't set each element to a memory location, we just set the whole array.

Comment: (a) Dynamic array could mean several things. Code is worth more than a 1000 words describing it. (b) Even dynamically allocated stuff have a **fixed** size.

Comment: `array that is too big for that memory slot`, How is this possible ? We define the array size during its declaration or initialization, so we know exactly the amount of memory required. Even if we don't utilize the complete array elements the memory is already reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using std::vector for these dynamic arrays, then it will be handled automatically as you can see in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)